# FTP framework to use in Java code

Tags: ftp, sftp

I need to do some FTP'ing in Java, is there a best FTP framework to use?
I see apache has something, any opinions?
I just need to do some simple "sftp" puts and gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unaware of a free Java solution that offers both ftp and sftp client support.

For sftp I have good experiences with the free and popular [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).  One downside, the documentation is minimal, but there are a number of blogs that offer code to get you started.